# Using Digest Authentication with Shelly Power Product, cannot get 200 code from second GET requests

Tags: c#, http-headers, rpc, digest-authentication

I'm working on getting some Shelly Power products ([API Documents Here](https://shelly-api-docs.shelly.cloud/gen2/General/Authentication/)) able to be called from a .NET 6 Minimal API application.

Following the Digest Authentication documentation from Shelly and the [RFC 7616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616.html), I have an extension method for the HttpClient that basically takes an HttpRequestMessage for the URL **http:///rpc/Switch.GetStatus?id=0**. After setting the normal headers (Accept, User-Agent, etc.) for that HttpRequestMessage, it passes that HttpRequestMessage as a parameter to that extension method.

After passing the HttpRequestMessage to the extension method, it is cloned into a new HttpRequestMessage, with the content, version, and headers. After that, the first SendAync() call is made, and the 401 response is generated containing the WWW-Authentication header. After parsing out the realm, nonce, and qop, the rounds of hashing is done according to the specs. Shelly uses SHA256 instead of MD5 (as they should) but overall follows the standard for hashing. After this, the newly formed Authentication Header string is created and it is formatted as such:

```
Digest username="admin", realm="shellyplugus-083af2018b68", nonce="633e7ba8", cnonce=8724224, response="9B15CEBA6E5FD862271954AC2C40948D6237511B83748143FF763A0E76B1A346", algorithm=SHA-256
```

The following code is the creation of an AuthHeaderObject, the creation of the string above, and gets added to the cloned HttpRequestMessage (called "digestRequest" here):

```
var digestAuthHeaders = new DigestAuthHeader(
            "Digest", realm, username, password, nonce, qop, clientNonce, "SHA-256");
var digestRequestHeader = digestAuthHeaders.DigestRequestHeader();
digestRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", digestRequestHeader);
```

The 2nd SendAsync() passing the cloned request and completion option enum.

```
var authRes = await client.SendAsync(digestRequest, httpCompletionOption);
```

The issue after this is that I am still getting a 401 response. Not even getting another code indicating another issue. It is just acting like the same request has been made.

Should I forgo the cloning of the HttpRequestMessage and simply create a new one? Does anything immediately standout that is incorrect? I want to note that Shelly only specifies that Authorization string only contain the values included, it does not require uri, qop, opaque, and some of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a direct way to do this by using HttpClientHanlder and setting the NetworkCredentials property, then passing the Handler to the HttpClient.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).